# Xcode 9.1 (9B55) Crashes every time I open the migration assistant

Tags: xcode

This is crashing Xcode every time:

Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax ...

Has anyone else seen this issue? Should I file a bug report with apple?

Comment: I'd try (re)downloading Xcode first. Even if try 9.2 - available on the developer site. (I didn't check the release notes, but maybe there's something there.)

Comment: 9.2b2 still crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, and it seems that the crash happens when any Xcode project on the workspace has a sub-project.
Removing the references to any such sub-project made the migration assistant not crash on open. But note that if a target doesn't build, the migration won't succeed, so you'll likely have to re-add the sub-project as a workspace top-level item or link to a copy of the sub-project framework that you build separately.

Comment: Looks like you are right, it doesn't crash on a project that doesn't have any sub-projects.